# Python Calculator inline command for multiplication doesn't work

Tags: python, calculator

```
import sys

def add(n1, n2):
    return n1 + n2

def subtract(n1, n2):
    return n1 - n2

def multiply(n1, n2):
    return n1 * n2

def divide(n1, n2):
    return n1 / n2

while len(sys.argv) > 1:
    formula = sys.argv[1]
    if formula[0].isnumeric():
        n1 = int(formula[0])
    else:
        print("NA")
        break
    operation = formula[1]

    if formula[2].isnumeric():
        n2 = int(formula[2])
    else:
        print("NA")
        break

    print(n1)
    print(operation)
    print(n2)

    if operation == "+":
        print(add(n1, n2))
        break
    if operation == "-":
        print(subtract(n1, n2))
        break
    if operation == "*":
        print(multiply(n1, n2))
        break
    if operation == "/":
        print(divide(n1, n2))
        break
```

[image: result]

This is the result I get when running a multiplication. How can I fix it?

```
desktop % python3 calc.py 4*2
zsh: no matches found: 4*2
```

Comment: Did you ensure that your arguments are getting passed to your python script?

Comment: Put the argument in quotes, since `*` has special meaning in the shell. It's for filename wildcards.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Python. You'd get the same error with `echo 4*2`

Comment: Unrelated, the `operator` module already has functional versions of the operators; no need to write your own wrappers.

Comment: pass it as a string. get the value from sys.argv[1]. split by char and cast accordinly

Answer (score 0):

A slight modification to you your loop treating each command line argument as a separate operand or operator may work better:

```
i = 1
while len(sys.argv) > 1:
    print(f"formula {formula}")
    if sys.argv[i].isnumeric():
        n1 = int(sys.argv[i])
        i += 1
    else:
        print("NA")
        break
    operation = sys.argv[i]
    i += 1

    if sys.argv[i].isnumeric():
        n2 = int(sys.argv[i])
    else:
        print("NA")
        break

    print(n1)
    print(operation)
    print(n2)

    if operation == "+":
        print(add(n1, n2))
        break
    if operation == "-":
        print(subtract(n1, n2))
        break
    if operation == "*":
        print(multiply(n1, n2))
        break
    if operation == "/":
        print(divide(n1, n2))
        break
```

This takes successive arguments from `sys.argv` and treating each an an operand (number) or operator (+,-,*,/).

Other have made helpful suggestions in the comments regarding ensuring all characters and program arguments are reaching your python program via `sys.argv` as you intend them rather than being treated in special ways by the shell.